# Assign the result of a query to a variable in powershell in Azure-Runbooks

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a runbook using automation in Azure.  It is getting a single integer result from a table and it can return the correct value.  The code I am using is below and it works.

```
 $SQLServerCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "SqlCredential"
 #Import the SQL Server Name from the Automation variable.
 $SQL_Server_Name = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "SqlServer"
 #Import the SQL DB from the Automation variable.
 $SQL_DB_Name = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "Database"


 $Query = "select max(je.ExecutionOrder) as LastStepExecuted
from PPoint.JobExecutionHistory je
where je.EventType = 'Start'
and je.JobRunId = PPoint.fnGetJobRunID()"

 invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$SQL_Server_Name" -Database "$SQL_DB_Name" -Credential $SQLServerCred -Query "$Query" -Encrypt
```

The next step for me is to assign the result from the query to a variable and then evaluate it to see if it should call another runbook. So I want to have a variable named LastStep and assign it the integer result of LastStepExecuted from the query below.  I then want to do something along this line (this is pseudocode)

```
if LastStep = 2147483647
 call another runbook
else
 do nothing - end the runbook
```

I have tried several ways to capture the LastStepExecuted in a variable but I can't figure it out.  Can anyone help?

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Start-AzAutomationRunbook** cmdlet to trigger a child runbook from the another run book inside the automation account.

```
$SQLServerCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "SqlCredential"
 #Import the SQL Server Name from the Automation variable.
 $SQL_Server_Name = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "SqlServer"
 #Import the SQL DB from the Automation variable.
 $SQL_DB_Name = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "Database"


 $Query = "select max(je.ExecutionOrder) as LastStepExecuted
from PPoint.JobExecutionHistory je
where je.EventType = 'Start'
and je.JobRunId = PPoint.fnGetJobRunID()"

$LastStep=invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$SQL_Server_Name" -Database "$SQL_DB_Name" -Credential $SQLServerCred -Query "$Query" -Encrypt

if($LastStep -eq 2147483647)
{
    Start-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "MyAutomationAccount" -Name "Test-ChildRunbook" -ResourceGroupName "LabRG" -DefaultProfile $AzureContext  -Parameters $params -Wait
}
else
{
    Write-Output "conditionfailed the value of $LastStep"
}
```

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-child-runbooks#:%7E:text=To%20call%20a%20runbook%20inline,be%20used%20in%20this%20way.) documentation, about modular runbooks in azure automation.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your response!  I tried your example, it didn't work until I changed the eq to an = sign.  i.e. if($LastStep = 2147483647) I don't know if -eq is meant to be pseudo code but it didn't work for me whereas the actual = sign did.

It still gives me an error when I call the other runbook but will detail on another thread.